# Quick assistance needed with PHP/mysql table values being entered

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to enter certain values to a db table and although its going through, not all
the values are being populated.

im going to skip some parts because again, its not that im not connecting etc, the problem is that although i am **getting** through and communicating with the db, on info upload, only certain fields are being populated.

so for example,

My "username / password " fields have the same values within the db so im not sure
why one field is being populated and the other is not...

but here is some code..theres alot of it so im gonna copy/paste the important parts

```
the html for example is

<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="Enter Desired Username"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="upass" id="upass" value="Enter Desired Password"/><br/>

etc...you know same old html
```

the php
the connection works etc..

the variables

```
$c2d = "the db connection here";
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$userPass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']);
```

//here i set up all my vars but this is the problematic one.

```
$addDetails2DbQueryS = "INSERT INTO accounts (appUname, appUpass)VALUES('$userName','$userPass')";

$addDetails2DbQueryS = "INSERT INTO accounts (appUname, appUpass) VALUES('$userName','$userPass')";
```

//perform some checks here like if the account thats being created already exist etc..
and this works as well too blah blah

then when all is good, add the account to the db
to which im using this

```
$addDetails2DbQuerySDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $addDetails2DbQueryS) or die("error [003] could not add acc to db" . mysqli_error);
```

And whats happening is, The username is logged but the password field is empty

Any ideas what im doing wrong? thanks in advance and
ANY help i gladly and humbly appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Try to display the content `$addDetails2DbQueryS` before executing the query and see if the password has value or not

Comment: hello BnW, what do you mean display?

Comment: I mean `echo $addDetails2DbQueryS;`

Comment: when i echo that var, what i get is this INSERT INTO accounts (appUname, appUpass) VALUES('testname','') testname being the dummy name im trying to register with...but the pass is empty just like in the db.

Comment: i echoed the password and its coming in empty...ive quadruple checked and all the names are the same, any reason why it wouldnt come through on POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre using the wrong escaping function... youre using `mysql_real_escape_string` from the [`ext/mysql`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension, but youre actually using the [`MySQLi`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension to do youre insert, so you should be using its version of the function `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Use one DB driver or the other, not both :-)

I would actually expect you to get `false` for both values because if you havent established a db connection with `mysql_connect` the calling `mysql_real_escape_string` should return false and generate a waring:

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>   last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is
>   found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
>   no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
>   level error is generated.

If you have estabished a `mysql_connect()` connection then i would expect your `mysqli_query()` to fail because you never established a connection with `mysqli_connect()`.

I think once you pick one of the 3 DB drivers and only use the classes/functions of ONE of those most of your issues are going to disapear:

1. [`PDO`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  (my favorite, elegant, pretty easy to use, easier to port code to a diff. db if needed)
2. [`MySQLi`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (offers the best range of MySQL specific features, but is clunkier to use)
3. [`ext/mysql`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (avoid like the plague when possible)

Comment: Hello Prodigitalson, Thanks for the throough answer. It did not fix my problem , but definitely caught a soon to be error lol. The problem i found is that somehow, on POST, the "password" isnt coming through EVEN though the value is the same as on the form. EDIT*** never mind. solved it ...so dumb lol, but you solved a soon to be problem so THANK YOU lol.